# How to use msbuild to build net6.0-android and not generate apk?

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, .net-6.0

I need use Command Line build net6 project and get dll, i use command "dotnet msbuild", but every time it will generate apk file when build Android project, apk is big,so build is slow, i want not generate apk, have any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I test some command,such as `dotnet msbuild` and `dotnet msbuild /t:Build /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:Configuration=Debug`

Finally, I found `dotnet msbuild /t:Build /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:AndroidBuildApplicationPackage=false` and set .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>false</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

that can just build and not generate apk.